# In TypeScript, when invoking a function, why can I hint that a null argument has some other type?

Tags: typescript

I was trying to understand how come in TypeScript line `A` compiles while line `B` does not.

```
function someFunction<T>(arg: T): void {
  console.log(arg)
}

someFunction<string>('some string') // obviously, it works
someFunction<string>(null)          // [A] compiles
someFunction<string>(2)             // [B] doesn't compile
```

In line `A`, I'm hinting the compiler that the argument is of type `string` while it is clearly not. However TypeScript will compile that line without emitting any errors.

This doesn't happen in line B. I'm passing a `number` and hinting that it is a `string`.

How come line `A` doesn't fail compiling? Is there a special case with the `null` type?

Despite my googling, I couldn't find a satisfactory explanation why this is. Providing links to resources explaining what is going on in my code is very welcome.

Comment: It fails in playground, with error: `Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)`. Can you post your `tsconfig.json`?  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmAHgBUA+ACgEMAnAcwC5EiBKBgNzhgBNEBvAWABQiRBASoANhgB04uDUq0mggL6DBqTDkiwEBZFCowwNcgHINGFAaM1TTROvTZcOwvsPHyYEOPH3hAYGOmi74etaeZABM-oFxwkA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you enable `strictNull` checking in your `tsconfig.json`, all types have implicitly `undefined` and `null` types. So when you type `string`, it is basically `string | undefined | null`. I definitely recommend enabling that option because it will catch alot of unwanted bugs.

You can read more about it here: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/intro/strictnullchecks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have `strict: true` in my `tsconfig.json`, which implies `strictNullChecks: true`. Plus, I think that under your assumption, line B would compile too, wouldn't it?

Comment: Line B wouldnt compile since 2 is a number, and not a string (TypeScript will not try to transform 2 to a string). Do you maybe have multiple tsconfig.json in your solution? Is maybe typechecking set as a warning in your compiler? I have tried your example and it works as intendeed: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhgUwM4wDwBUB8AFAIYBOA5gFzK4CUyA3sMi8lEhggDZoB0XCciQq0A3MAC+44OizYspOBHJEIYLlzHAgA

Comment: you can check that it has nothing to do with generics to simply try to do this:  const test:string = null; (it should fail if strict is emabled)

Comment: Actually you're right, I wasn't using `strict`. Thank you for your help.